# Title Fact Opinion

Tags: grammar

What does `Title Fact Opinion`refer to in the sense of a gramatical construction, or as a function word.  My girlfriend has to define it. I have been speaking english my entire life, but I have no idea what this vocabulary word means, or to what it is referring.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

No google searches, M-W dictionary searches, or anything else that I can think of have come back with any responses.

Comment: Can we have a bit more context? Where did she find this phrase? Out of context it doesn't mean anything. But if we know where this was found, we might be able to help.

Comment: It is from a `Function Word Vocuabulary List` I had no idea where else to go for this one, and since I'm already a member of several other exchange groups, I thought that this might be the place to go.

Comment: Hmm. Could you post other phrases from the vocabulary list? If they fit a pattern then maybe we can figure it out. A strange vocabulary term, I must admit!

Comment: If you Google (in quotes) "Title: Fact or Opinion" you will find many lesson plans, flashcards, worksheets and the like so described. I think somebody did a cut-and-paste and didn't edit properly.

Comment: And Welcome to ELU!

Comment: Thank you all, I agree with you StoneyB, it seems that there must have been some poorly copied items on the list, having looked at it closer, I've found a couple of others as well.  If you put an answer I will accept it!

Comment: As you wish. Hope your girlfriend didn't get too fried!

Comment: On closer inquiry the phrase in question turned out to be an editing mistake.

Comment: @StoneyB Good catch. I seconded your vote to close the question, but the OT reasons still leave that automatic downvote :/ I think there's a discussion somewhere on MSO about removing that, but in the meantime I've give an +1 to offset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Google (in quotes) "Title: Fact or Opinion" you will find many lesson plans, flashcards, worksheets and the like so described.

It looks to me like somebody did a cut-and-paste and didn't edit properly.